# Why does rendering an iframe into jsdom with ReactTestUtils not provide a contentWindow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, jsdom

I'm trying to test a React component that renders an iframe and injects markup directly into that iframe. (I'm not trying to load a URL in the iframe.)

The component actually works quite well in a browser, but writing a test for it so far seems to be impossible. I'm not sure why.

Here is a shortened test case which proves the failure.

```
    // Set up DOM
    var jsdom = require( 'jsdom' ).jsdom;
    global.document = jsdom( '' );
    global.window = document.defaultView;
    global.navigator = document.defaultView.navigator;

    // Prepare React
    var ReactTestUtils = require( 'react-addons-test-utils' );
    var React = require( 'react' );

    var Frame = React.createClass( {
      componentDidMount() {
        console.log( 'iframe loaded. adding content' );
        const iframe = this.refs.iframe;
        console.log( 'adding content to', iframe.contentWindow ); // Should not be null
        iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
        iframe.contentWindow.document.write( 'Hello World!' );
        iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
      },

      render() {
        console.log( 'rendering iframe' );
        return React.createElement( 'iframe', { ref: 'iframe' } );
      }
    } );

    // Render the component
    ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument( React.createElement( Frame ) );
```

To run this, you'll need the following npm packages installed: jsdom, react, react-addons-test-utils. You should be able to then run the above code using node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested your code pretty thoroughly and ended up finding the issue to be `ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument`.

`ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument` creates a container for the Component, but doesn't attach to the DOM (anymore), thus why `contentWindow` will be null for `iframe` elements. If you read the comments in the `ReactTestUtils` source you'll notice they are considering renaming `renderIntoDocument` because technically it doesn't! 
The solution, it seems, is to use directly `ReactDOM` instead.

Here is a bit of code from the `ReactTestUtils` source:

```
var ReactTestUtils = {
  renderIntoDocument: function (instance) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    // None of our tests actually require attaching the container to the
    // DOM, and doing so creates a mess that we rely on test isolation to
    // clean up, so we're going to stop honoring the name of this method
    // (and probably rename it eventually) if no problems arise.
    // document.documentElement.appendChild(div);
    return ReactDOM.render(instance, div);
  },
 }
```

Using `ReactDOM` with your test case works:

```
// Set up DOM
var jsdom = require( 'jsdom' ).jsdom;
global.document = jsdom( '' );
global.window = document.defaultView;
global.navigator = document.defaultView.navigator;

// Prepare React
var ReactTestUtils = require( 'react-addons-test-utils' );
var React = require( 'react' ); 
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')

var Frame = React.createClass( {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log( 'iframe loaded. adding content' );
    const iframe = this.refs.iframe;

    console.log( 'adding content to', iframe.contentWindow ); // Should not be null
    iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
    iframe.contentWindow.document.write( 'Hello World!' );
    iframe.contentWindow.document.close();

    // Should log "Hello World!"
    console.log(iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);
  },

  render() {
    console.log( 'rendering iframe' );
    return React.createElement( 'iframe', { ref: 'iframe' } );
  }
} );

// Render the component

// NOPE 
//ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument( React.createElement( Frame ) );

// YUP
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Frame), document.body)
```

It's too bad that this isn't mentioned in the docs for `ReactTestUtils`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the iframe to your document before contentWindow will become available.

Check this code:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
console.log(iframe.contentWindow);

document.body.appendChild(iframe);

console.log(iframe.contentWindow);
```